# Excel crashes on user defined DLL when UDF call is based on the output of another UDF

Tags: c++, visual-studio, excel, dll, user-defined-functions

I have wrote a dll file that can be used by Excel, however my spreadsheet crashes on certain circumstances. I would be grateful if some one can help me out.

The C++ code that I am using is as follows: (largely borrowed from C++ package QuantLib)

```
long __stdcall nextBusinessDay_C(long todaySerial) {
    Date today(todaySerial);
    UnitedStates us(UnitedStates::NYSE);
    return (long)(us.advance(today,1,Days).serialNumber());
}
```

In Excel, I have the following VBA code

```
Declare Function yz_nextBusinessDayUS_NYSE_C Lib _
    "c:\lib\myExcelFile.dll" _
(ByVal ds As Long) As Long

Function nextBizDayUS(d As Date) As Date
    nextBizDayUS = nextBusinessDayUS_C(CLng(d))
End Function
```

Now, in Excel, if I only use:

```
//This works perfectly fine
A1: 1/1/2013         B1: =nextBizDayUS(A1)
A2: 1/2/2013         B2: =nextBizDayUS(A2)
A3: 1/2/2013         B3: =nextBizDayUS(A3)
...                  ...
```

I can continue to write thousands of lines like this without any problem. However, if I use the output of one function as the input to another, my Excel crashes every time when I hit Ctrl+Alt+F9:

```
//This crashes every time when I hit Ctrl+Alt+F9!!!
A1: 1/1/2013
A2: =nextBizDayUS(A1)
A3: =nextBizDayUS(A2)
```

The source code using in my C++ library is exactly the same as the QuantLib package (I am just trying to learn this package, not marketing my own code) The only fancy stuff the code uses is boost::shared_ptr<>.

I have being bothered by this for many days. Hopefully some one can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you add `DoEvents` after this line? `nextBizDayUS = nextBusinessDayUS_C(CLng(d))`

Comment: It might be a calculation sequence problem: try changing your data types from date to variant and adding IF IsEmpty(d) then exit function as the first line of your VBA function

Comment: @k4knight have you gotten the answer to your issue? If not comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the replies. I have figured it out.

The file crashes because my C++ function throws an exception when accepting a 0 value as the input date. In excel, if I have the following sheet:

```
A1: 1/1/2013
A2: =nextBizDayUS(A1)
A3: =nextBizDayUS(A2)
```

Once I press Ctrl+Alt+F9, nextBizDayUS will be evaluated 3 times in the following order:

```
=nextBizDayUS(0)  'cell A3
=nextBizDayUS(A1)  'cell A2
=nextBizDayUS(A2)  'cell B3
```

Not sure why Excel does this, but to solve the problem I simply need to add a special case in my C++ function to handle the 0 value input.